# Acessar biblioteca de fotos pelo aplicativo android

Tags: android

Olá. Gostaria de desenvolver um aplicativo que ao clicar em uma imagem (ImageView) acessa a camera e depois de tirar a foto atualiza o ImageView com a imagem. Também tem outra imagem (ImageView1) e se clicar acessa a biblioteca de fotos para escolher uma foto. Após escolher a foto, atualiza o ImageView1.
Eu consegui resolver a parte de acessar a camera clicando no ImageView mas não consegui fazer a parte de acessar a biblioteca de fotos, selecionar uma foto e substituir pela atual.
Acredito que muita coisa do meu código pode ser aproveitada.

Meu código

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ImageView img;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            abrirCamera();
        }
    });
}

public void abrirCamera(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent,0);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    img.setImageBitmap(bp);

}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // adiciona itens para a barra de ação, se ela estiver presente.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;

}
}
```

Meu XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/imagemcamera"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView1" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
    android:src="@drawable/fotos"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Clique para acessar as fotos do celular"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Clique para acessar a camera do celular"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luiz, boa noite! 
Consegui carregar as imagens da minha bibioteca, porém só funcionou para as imagens do what's up (talvez pelo tamanho das mesmas. De qualquer forma segue o código:

Primeiramente no AndroidManifest.xml, antes da tag application:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Agora na classe principal (MainActivity):

```
private Bitmap bitmap;

public void carregarGaleria(){
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
   intent.setType("image/*");
   intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
   startActivityForResult(intent,1);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    InputStream stream = null;
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            if (bitmap != null) {
                bitmap.recycle();
            }
            stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
            imgl.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if (stream != null)
                try {
                    stream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

    }
}
```

Agora basta setar na img1 o onClickListener chamando o carregarGaleria().

OBS: o código está grande porque coloquei todos os try/catch de possíveis erros. Testa aí e me avisa se funcionou. Abraço.

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado. O único problema é que preciso tratar o acesso a camera e posteriormente atualizar uma foto tirada por ela em uma ImageView e também um acesso a biblioteca para selecionar uma foto e atualizar uma outra ImageView. Não estou conseguindo integrar esses dois processos dentro de um único "onActivityResult". O código que fiz e compartilhei somente trata a situação pela câmera. Outra coisa que achei estranha, após tirar a foto e seleciona-la, ela atualiza a ImageView porém num tamanho muito reduzido, não achei nada para retornar a foto do tamanho da ImageView @MagnusMaker

Comment: Basta vc colocar um (if requestcode == 0) dentro da onActivityResult e definir o tratamento, pois a chamada para tirar foto está definida como 0 no seu código, o código que passei para abrir a galeria retorna o requestcode == 1 (note que coloquei if requestcode==1 para tratar do meu código), para não conflitar entendeu? Com relação ao tamanho eu realmente ainda não sei como resolver...

Comment: Entendi agora, faz sentido. Mais uma vez, muito obrigado. Vou validar quanto a alteração do tamanho e se achar, atualizo aqui. Boa noite @MagnusMaker

Comment: Surgiu mais uma dúvida. Não sei se você chegou a identificar essa situação. Implementei o código que você passou e consigo acessar minha biblioteca de imagens. Todas as fotos são exibidas e é possível selecionar qualquer foto e substituir pelo ImageView, EXCETO as fotos tiradas pela câmera. Um exemplo disso é o fato de eu ter utilizado esse código também para acessar a câmera do celular, tirar foto e depois adicionar a foto na ImageView. Quando tiro a foto e a seleciono, é como se ficasse invisível no ImageView. @MagnusMaker